# getting Unclosed character class near index when using this regex in my java programme ^(?!\s)((?![_\-=^":*?<>^$!@#%&\/\~*\\\]\(){}[|+=":;'?><,|]).)*$

Tags: java, regex

getting Unclosed character class near index 62 when using this regex in my java programm

```
^(?!\s)((?![_\-=^":*?<>^$!@#%&\/\~*\\\]\(){}[|+=":;'?><,|]).)*$
```

How to resolve it

Please tell me how to resolve this error what changes needed to be make to get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

You might need to escape the String literals " to not end the string prematurely.

^(?!\s)((?![_-=^\":?<>^$!@#%&/~](){}[|+=\":;'?><,|]).)*$

should to the trick. Note the preceeding \ in front of each "

This should lead you to a line like this:

```java
String regex = "^(?!\s)((?![_-=^\":?<>^$!@#%&/~\](){}[|+=\":;'?><,|]).)*$";
```

If the regex does not work as intended, you might need to add a double escaping back slash like:

```java
String regex = "^(?!\s)((?![_-=^\\":?<>^$!@#%&/~\](){}[|+=\\":;'?><,|]).)*$";
```

Comment: hi can you plz tell me what exact changes i need to made make this work fine

Comment: Note the preceeding \ in front of each " - Try to place \ or \\ in front of each " in your regex.

Comment: In my answer I also added two examples how you could define your regex in your code.